# Demonstrate that the sides opposite these are proportional, ie $ \frac {BC} {B'C'} = \frac {AC} {A'C '} $

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Given two triangles $ ABC $ and $ A'B'C '$ that have two equal angles, $ \angle A = \angle A' $, and two supplementary angles, $ \angle B = \angle B '= 180 $ degrees, demonstrate that the sides opposite these are proportional, ie $ \frac {BC} {B'C'} = \frac {AC} {A'C '} $

Can anyone give me a tip? I tried to apply similarity to triangles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extend $BC$ through point $B$ to point $D$ such that $\angle BAD=\angle  B'A'C'$.

Now,  observe that, $\triangle DAB\sim \triangle C'A'B'$ and thereafter $\frac {DA}{DB} =\frac {C'A'}{B'C'}$.

Also,  $AB$ is the bisector of $\angle DAC$ and thereafter $\frac {DA}{DB}=\frac {AC}{BC}$. Comparing this with the equation obtained earlier gives the desired result.